# How to Keep Variable Assignment When Using %%time Magic Function?

Tags: python, jupyter

When I run cells in Jupyter that have the `%%time` magic function, any variables I assign are not saved.

Cell 1:

```
%%time
a = 5

--> CPU times: user 3 µs, sys: 0 ns, total: 3 µs
    Wall time: 7.15 µs
```

Cell 2:

```
a
--> NameError: name 'a' is not defined
```

How can I save the variable a?

Comment: Actions done in a `%timeit` do not affect the namespace outside it - that's by design.  Do that `a=5` assignment separately.  `timeit` is for timing, not production.

Answer (score 0):

Running on [CoLab](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1QN0FgCHTLlR4oVVdrK4IsvoG_Btj9hv7/view?usp=sharing) didn't reproduced the probelm. 
In order to have `a` be saved on a Jupyter notebook, you have to run all cells. 
Running the second cell only causes such problems.

Comment: The problem arises for me in JupyterLab. Can I ask, when you say "you have to run all cells", are you certain there is no other way to do it, or you're just aware that this is one way to do it? For me, I don't want to have to use that functionality because it's a large notebook and many cells take minutes to run.

Comment: That's exactly the issue: you MUST run the cell where a is defined before using it. You don't have to run all the cells before it, just this one.